# Ubuntu not showing up in boot menu or anywhere after installing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I tried dual-booting Ubuntu 20, on an HP Laptop with Windows 11 (Updated from Windows 10, laptop was a windows 10 device by default). Created 3 partitions for Ubuntu, /home, /, swap. However, after successful installation, GRUB bootloader doesn't show up. Even in the boot menu, there is no sign of Ubuntu anywhere.

Tried this command: bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Still no results. Help would be really appreciated.

Laptop: HP, UEFI With GPT.

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as Ubuntu 20

Comment: that is, you can launch Windows like previously? what does Disk Management show?